# 504 gateway timeout while import customer address CSV In Magento2

Tags: import, magento2.3

> http://website.com/admin/admin/import/validate/key/40cc16dabfa0d1fb09a6cb9e62433b9880e4f3f0e024eb1c517d832fa47c225d/?form_key=s235x0mqERyjXLqX 504 (Gateway Timeout)
>   `validation.js:185

while Import customer address csv in admin.
What is solution?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a timeout issue on the server. Check your max_execution_time in php.ini or .htaccess for your site